Must an autonomous system be internally fully connected?
Must every part of an autonomous system be connected inside the system to every other part, or can it be split in two (or more) distinct parts which are only connected through other autonomous systems?
It seems that BGP routing wouldn't work properly in a split AS, because routers in each part would reject routes originated by each other part with the same AS number, thinking they would create routing loops.

Packets are routed by IP address, not AS. Different parts of an AS will advertise routes they have, not routes the other have.

Inside an AS you‘d use iBGP, OSPF or something else…

Remember that BGP, and any other routing protocols, does not route packets. BGP simply exchanges routing information. Packets are routed by IP address.

You are incorrect. Packets are routed by what is in the routing table. That is routing, Deciding what does or does not go in the routing table is not routing. If I connect my router (my AS) to two different routers that have the same AS number, but are not connected to each other in any way, each advertises different networks, and my router routes the packets to the correct router, despite them having the same AS number because routers route by IP address, not AS number.

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael BGP is a routing protocol that exchanges routes between routers, but it doesn't route packets and it doesn't decide where packets go either. That's up to the routing table or FIB that's fed by the routing protocols.

It's common for CDNs to use the same ASN in many isolated "islands" where they have points-of-presence but no backbone interconnecting them.
On the CDN side, they'll configure their BGP router to learn paths with its own ASN from eBGP sessions -- for example, paths like 64500 1 64500 where 1 is a transit provider used by the CDN, and 64500 is the CDN's AS.
In Junos this may be configured like set protocols bgp group <foo> family inet loops 2 (doc link) or alternately can be configured globally for the AS (link).
The transit provider (AS 1 in the above example) also must ensure it advertises routes to its customer CDN (64500) which already have that ASN in the path.  In Junos this is accomplished by configuring advertise-peer-as (doc link).
In my experience, forgetting these config items is also a very common mistake at smaller CDNs and other types of networks with separate islands using the same ASN.  It is consequential -- you end up relying on default routes or static routes to reach other parts of your own network, and that may be undesirable.
Each network should decide for itself if re-using the same ASN in separate islands is best for it.

That works well when the islands don't ever need to talk to each other, which for a CDN is very likely.

@Ricky the purpose of using loops & advertise-peer-as configuration is so the islands can communicate while maintaining BGP fault tolerance.  Without this config, they would need default routes.

Like many networking questions, the answer to this is "It depends."
You are right that loop detection is based on detecting one's own ASN in prefix announcements. So in theory, BGP would reject announcements with the same ASN as you described.
In practice, however, many things can change this.

All major implementations of BGP allow the loop prevention mechanism
to be overridden or disabled for a set of announcements.
The AS path attribute can also be edited so that specific ASNs in the
path can be added, rewritten, or removed.
An intervening AS can redistribute routes using another protocol,
removing all original AS Path information and essentially disabling
the loop detection mechanism.
A tunneling mechanism can be used to make the split ASes "logically appear" as a single AS


And there's always static routes.
